# Where to see the output of a microsoft nni run AFTER trial has finished?

Tags: neural-network

https://nni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/WebUI.html

The docs basically work but when it finishes you have nothing. No ui, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After you ran "nnictl create" or "nnictl resume", go to this link:
http://localhost:8080/

The WebUI will be loaded and you can check via http client

Or you can check the output in the nni-user folder (on Windows):
C:\Users\%USER_PROFILE\nni\experiments\